# HTTP header Location with urlencoded

Tags: apache, http, header, location

I am trying to reproduce an issue in a lab environment.
I have a http apache server and I want to send a Location header with an urlencoded. In my production environment is simantec who codes url and when I receive it it is coded. In my lab I am not able to code the url, thats why I am trying to do that apache server send location header with urlencoded.
This is what I have:

```
<Location /ma1>
Header always set Location http://www.example.com
</Location>
```

That works, but then I'd like to receive a encoded Location which I should parse in the load balancer.
I should write an iRule in F5 to decode that but I don't know how to make the server to send that.
If I change uri to http%3a%2f%2fexample%2ecom I am getting a syntax error when I restart the server.

```
may 24 16:19:04 sdn-huawei--001 apache2[29663]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 295 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
may 24 16:19:04 sdn-huawei--001 apache2[29663]: Unrecognized header format %3
```

I haven't found how to do this.
Any help?
I get  literally urlencoded("http://www.example.com")

I need to test this because I have to read Location header to modify private uri to public uri.